# In app menubar won't show after removing global menu widget

Tags: kde, appmenu, globalmenu

**once** I have used global menu widget, and after removing it, whatever I do, the in application menu won't return.

Except create another user.

Actually I know that. I deserved it. XD

Note : On a new user, if I add the global menu widget to a panel and remove it then, this is not going to happen.

Comment: Note : On a new user, if I add the global menu widget to a panel and remove it then, this is not going to happen.  Is this a question you are asking?

Comment: No. I mean the case in the "Note" won't trigger the situation I meet, the disappearing of in app menubar.

Comment: I would expect it would.

Answer (score 3):

Well, simply, my question is about after using global menu widget the menu bar won't come back to the application title.

For example, we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to hide/show menu bar like in Konsole. But under my condition it's on the global menu and won't show.

Happily, today I found a possible solution.

Go System settings → *Startup and Shutdown* → *Background Services* and find and uncheck *Application menus daemon*. Log out or reboot and it will turn back.

- Reference: [How to enable standard menu bar?](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=167547&p=436510&hilit=horizontal+menu#p436510)

Comment: I ran into this issue just now on latest KDE Manjaro. In my case the CTRL+(SHIFT)+M shortcut was still needed after disabling the service and a reboot. Some applications (konsole, kate) needed to be turned on/off a few times and I needed to use the shortcut a few times to get it to toggle. Initially ran into an issue with DaVinci Resolve which apparently does not work with the Global Menu while the menu was hidden. Closing and starting the application a few times and using the shortcut several times managed to turn on the menu. Does not help that CTRL+M is a shortcut in DaVinci.